# Bash script to file line by line checking the condition if matches then add the starting value as # character

Tags: bash

```
  #!/bin/bash
    set -x
    chmod 777 /etc/filesystem.txt
    filename="/etc/filesystem.txt"
    n=#
    awk '!/#/ && /ab.com/ && /xyz/ {print $0}' /etc/filesystem.txt
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    while read line; do
    echo "$n$line"
    done < $filename >>/etc/abc.txt
    fi
```

Expected output is reading line by line in file, adding # value at staring of lines which satisfies the awk output.

```
example: input filesystem.txt

/dev/f1
/dev/f2
#/dev/f3
/dev/ab.com
/dev/xyz

expected output:

/dev/f1
/dev/f2
#/dev/f3
#/dev/ab.com
#/dev/xyz
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '!/^#/ && (/xyz/ || /ab\.com/) {$0="#"$0}1' /etc/filesystem.txt > /etc/abc.txt
$ cat /etc/abc.txt
/dev/f1
/dev/f2
#/dev/f3
#/dev/ab.com
#/dev/xyz
```

Comment: To the O.P. (@Ravi) . The whole design of `awk` processing is an implied `while` loop (`awk '{.....}' file` (the curly braces delimit the `while`d code) like  you have written in your bash script. To call `awk` inside of the bash `while` is super ineffcient. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it could be a single `sed` script.

```
sed '/^[^#].*((ab\.com)\|(xyz))/s/^/#/' /etc/filesystem.txt > /etc/abc.txt
```

`s/^/#` substitutes the empty string at the beginning of the line with `#`, but is only applied to a line if it starts with something other than `#` and contains `ab.com` or `xyz`.

Comment: Thanks; I always overlook the difference between basic and extended regular expressions.

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, it's past time for BREs to just quietly go away...